# Jquery select div element inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello people hope you can help me.

I am trying to select div elements that are inside another div and store either it's id or class. I tried to do this simple function to see if it works:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

However everytime I click on any div for example div with id "content" output I get is "content-link2".

Therefore my question is how to change that code so it looks inside 
div "content-link2"

```
<div id="content-link2">
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo">
    </div>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;"><p>hlo</p></div>
    <div id="comments">
        <form name="forma">
            <textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" class="refresh" cols="40" rows="5">Comments here...
            </textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ready!" id="send-data"><!--onClick="writeComment(e);"--> 
            <div id="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true">
                <p>This text can be by the user.</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Which div are you clicking? And which div are you trying to select?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation about selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and in you case you need to pay attention to this selector https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: When I test your code and click on `#comments` I get *two* alerts, first `"comments"`, then `"content-link2"`. That's because the click is sent up the DOM. Akshay posted the proper solution to this issue, *if* that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little change your `script`.

Here is solution of alerting an `id` of any element was clicked. If it hasn't id, alert shows `undefined`

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-link2">
    <title>Template 1</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <div class="logo">
        <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo">
    </div>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;"><p>hlo</p></div>
    <div id="comments">
        <form name="forma">
            <textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" class="refresh" cols="40" rows="5">Comments here...
            </textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ready!" id="send-data"><!--onClick="writeComment(e);"--> 
            <div id="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true">
                <p>This text can be by the user.</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG awesome works as it should do. This will go as accepted answer as soon as I am able to

Comment: Hm... while you commented it, I've just some changed a code: replace `document` with `'#content-link2'` . should get back?

Comment: IT was: `$(document).on('click', function(e){`. It became: `$('#content-link2').on('click', 'div', function(e){`.  Snippet still works.

Comment: rolled back the snippet

Comment: Question is answered however I have 1 more problem and I don't want to post another question for it. I want to save that div id into a variable and use it to change css on click. have a look at this code if you can https://jsfiddle.net/mbqzL73r/ but you don't have

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sjduabsw/1/ - but first you should click on div, then select color

Answer (score 0):

**you are getting that because of event bubbling try this**

```
$('div').on('click', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: This output only "content-link2" and not elements inside it

Answer (score 0):

You were close, what you need to do is:

```
$('#content-link2 > div').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This way you are targeting all of the child elements of the parent `div`. You can see [an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/dvqv3tkf/).